# Django Rest Conditions Giving Unexpected Results

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I'm using [rest_condition](https://github.com/caxap/rest_condition) within Django Rest Framework. **If any of my conditions fail I require access to be denied**. I declared my first permission on the view like so:

```
permission_condition = CustomPermissions
```

Which overrides [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) permission methods `has_permission` and `has_object_permission`.

**CustomPermissions**:

```
 def has_permission(self, request, view):
     return True

 def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
     return False
```

This works when accessing a detail endpoint:

Results:

```
> CustomPermissions
     - has_permission = True
     - has_object_permission = False
Result Expected Access defined : Actual Result Access defined - worked
```

However, When I add a second permission I don't get the desired outcome. I am expecting it to be, why?

```
permission_condition = (C(permissions.IsAdminUser) | C(CustomPermissions))
```

**IsAdminUser**

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):
    return False
```

Results:

```
> CustomPermissions
     - has_permission = True
     - has_object_permission = False
> IsAdminUser
     - True
Result Expected Access defined : Actual Result Access to view granted.
```

One can assume my logic or understanding of the conditions in  `permission_condition` is incorrect.

Comment: Is this `(C(permissions.IsAdminUser) | C(CustomPermissions))` checking for either of the permissions to result `True` like an `OR` operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the logic in the condition, below works.

```
permission_condition = (C(permissions.IsAdminUser) & C(CustomPermissions))
```

Comment: that's what exactly I was trying to assert in my comments. ;)